# How to add Theme Customizer Color?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'd like to add multiple options for the Color section of Wordpress Customizer, this is my code (the lower code (starter_new_setting_name2) overrides the upper):

```
function starter_customize_register( $wp_customize ) 
{
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'starter_new_section_name' , array(
        'title'    => __( 'Visible Section Name'),
        'priority' => 30
    ) );   

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'starter_new_setting_name' , array(
        'default'   => '#04A0c0',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __( 'H1 Color', 'starter' ),
        'section'  => 'starter_new_section_name',
        'settings' => 'starter_new_setting_name'
    ) ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'starter_new_setting_name2' , array(
        'default'   => '#AAAFFF',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __( 'H2 Color', 'starter2' ),
        'section'  => 'starter_new_section_name',
        'settings' => 'starter_new_setting_name2'
    ) ) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'starter_customize_register');
```

I have tried this person's code ([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186006/customize-register-with-multiple-controls-settings-how-to-get-values)) and that worked in having multiple sections but not for the color above:

```
function mcs_social($wp_customize){

    $wp_customize->add_section('mcs_social_handle', array(
        'title'    => __('Social Network Handles', 'mcs'),
        'description' => 'i.e., Acme Company\'s Facebook is https://facebook.com/acmecompany then enter "acmecompany"',
        'priority' => 70,
    ));

    //  =============================
    //  = Facebook                  =
    //  =============================
    $wp_customize->add_setting('mcs_fb_op', array(
        'default'        => '',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'theme_mod',

    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('mcs_fb', array(
        'label'      => __('Facebook Handle', 'mcs'),
        'section'    => 'mcs_social_handle',
        'settings'   => 'mcs_fb_op',
    ));

        //  =============================
    //  = Twitter                  =
    //  =============================
    $wp_customize->add_setting('mcs_tw_op', array(
        'default'        => '',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'theme_mod',

    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('mcs_tw', array(
        'label'      => __('Twitter Handle', 'mcs'),
        'section'    => 'mcs_social_handle',
        'settings'   => 'mcs_tw_op',
    ));

    //  =============================
    //  = RSS                       =
    //  =============================
     $wp_customize->add_setting('mcs_rs_op', array(
        'default'        => 'rss2_url',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'theme_mod',

    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'mcs_rs', array(
        'settings' => 'mcs_rs_op',
        'label'   => 'RSS Feed',
        'section' => 'mcs_social_handle',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'choices'       => array(
        'rdf_url'       => 'RDF/RSS 1.0 feed',
        'rss2_url'  => 'RSS 2.0 feed',
        'atom_url'  => 'Atom feed',
        ),
    ));
}

//add
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mcs_social' );
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got duplicate control IDs:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
```

And:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
```

They're both `link_color`, but they need unique IDs. Simplest option is to use the setting IDs:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'starter_new_setting_name', array(
```

And:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'starter_new_setting_name2', array(
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that link_color is a fixed setting. Thanks for the help, Jacob Peattie, made your response the accepted answer :), I still am not eligible for the +1, sorry. 

Mind helping with this?: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344687/check-theme-plugin-text-domain-does-not-match-the-themes-slug)

Comment: I'm not well versed on localization I'm afraid.

Comment: It's alright, thanks anyway.